# Problem in Inserting Datas in SQL Serve 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I created a talbe in SQL SERVER 2005 with Identity column. When i tried to insert the values to the table i'm getting error message and the values are not getting inserted.

**Please find my table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales](
    [SalesID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Year] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Month] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [TradeStartDate] [date] NULL,
    [TradeEndDate] [date] NULL,
    [Notes] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Sales] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SalesID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

****Error Message****

An explicit value for the identity column in table 'SHSReporting.dbo.Sales' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Kindly help to solve this problem

Thanks in Advance

- Ranga

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because when you are inserting data into your table, you are specifying a value for `[SalesID]`

Which is already autogenerated. Remove the value for `SalesID` and don't list it as one of your columns.

Comment: Either that, or if OP for some reason actually has unique values for SalesId, then SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Sales ON before the insert, and SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Sales OFF afterwards